# Paypal API , credit card to multiple receivers

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I am working on a mobile app , where a buyer needs to purchase products from multiple sellers, through credit card purchase. So basically I need paypal API , for transferring money to multiple receivers paypal account from the credit card information of the buyer.
I know there is a MassPay API, but that uses the API signature of the account, and I have the credit card information of the buyer and from there I want to pay to multiple sellers.
Paypal Documentation is no worth at all , confusing and cheap , and I am stucked .
Please help me , and provide me the exact way , not just a paypal documentation link , if you have anything for me.
I'm stucked .. :(

Answer (score 0):

PayPal doesn't have any API calls for sending credit card payments to multiple receivers. Through Chained or Parallel Payments you can send PayPal payments to several people. The buyer would be required to go to the PayPal checkout page though.

If you want to learn more about Adaptive Payments you can check this guide:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Or I can help you out.